# No Fields in XamDataGrid

Tags: xamdatagrid

Good day!

I have datasource, which is 100% pupulated. I'm sure in it because when AutoGenerateFields property is set to True all availble data is received and successfully displayed. But, what i really need to achieve is to display only fixed set of fields. If i set AutoGenerateFields to False i receive all record the same way, but NO columns at all.

Here is my XAML code:

```xml
<igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
  <igDP:FieldLayout >
    <igDP:FieldLayout.Settings>
        <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AutoArrangeCells="Never"/>
     </igDP:FieldLayout.Settings>
     <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
        <igDP:Field Name="Article" Label="Article" Row="0" Width="Auto"  IsScrollTipField="True" Column="0"/>
        <igDP:Field Name="Condition" Label="Condition" Row="0" Width="Auto" Column="1"/>
        <igDP:Field Name="Description" Label="Description" Row="0" Width="Auto" Column="2"/>
        <igDP:Field Name="Standartprice" Label="St. price" Row="0" Width="Auto" IsScrollTipField="True" Column="3"/>
        <igDP:Field Name="Listprice" Label="List price" Width="Auto" Row="0" Column="4" />
        <igDP:UnboundField Name="RowDetails" Row="1" Column="0" ColumnSpan="4">                 

     </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
   </igDP:FieldLayout>
 </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
```

I can't understand where is **the trouble** in my XAML markup.
I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 5):

You must make sure that the `Name` you give the field matches exactly to the bound datasource's properties. If one of them is wrong it will not display any, remember that it is also case sensitive.

Should `Standartprice` be `StandardPrice`?

Answer (score 1):

DarkIce's comment is probably right. To help with locating the specific Field involved, you can also check the Output tab in Visual Studio, where incorrectly named bindings will be reported.

That said, that hasn't always solved the problem for me when the mysterious "blank grid" appears, but it's the first place I look.